# Instantiated prefab shows up in hierarchy as inactive

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an issue where my prefab gun shows up as inactive in my hierarchy after I instantiated it.

```
void IInteractableTarget.Interact(GameObject character)
{
    int winningInt = Random.Range(1, 3);

    if(winningInt == 1)
    {
        GameObject obj_rifle = Instantiate(assaultRiflePrefab, spawnPos.position, spawnPos.rotation);
    }

    if (winningInt == 2)
    {
        GameObject obj_pistol = Instantiate(pistolPrefab, spawnPos.position, spawnPos.rotation);
    }

    //GameObject obj = Instantiate(assaultRiflePrefab, spawnPos.position, spawnPos.rotation);
    //obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.up * 5, ForceMode.Impulse);
    //Instantiate(assaultRiflePrefab, spawnPos.position, spawnPos.rotation);

    Debug.Log("Weapon from chest instantiated" + " " + winningInt);
}
```

[image]

How should I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

> The active status of a GameObject at the time of cloning is
> maintained, so if the original is inactive the clone is created in an
> inactive state too.

You can just set the active status of the GameObjects to `true`

```
void IInteractableTarget.Interact(GameObject character)
{
    int winningInt = Random.Range(1, 3);

    if(winningInt == 1)
    {
        GameObject obj_rifle = Instantiate(assaultRiflePrefab, spawnPos.position, spawnPos.rotation);
        obj_rifle.SetActive(true); // <-- Set active to true
    }

    if (winningInt == 2)
    {
        GameObject obj_pistol = Instantiate(pistolPrefab, spawnPos.position, spawnPos.rotation);
        obj_pistol.SetActive(true); // <-- Set active to true
    }

    //GameObject obj = Instantiate(assaultRiflePrefab, spawnPos.position, spawnPos.rotation);
    //obj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.up * 5, ForceMode.Impulse);
    //Instantiate(assaultRiflePrefab, spawnPos.position, spawnPos.rotation);

    Debug.Log("Weapon from chest instantiated" + " " + winningInt);
}
```

Comment: I tried that before and it didnt work. But I tried it again and it still shows up as inactive in the scene.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that you set its active state to `false` somewhere else. Maybe the prefab has a script which sets itself to be inactive?

Comment: There has to be something with the 3rd party asset. Now it works every like 1/5 times i try...? :s

Comment: It was the 3rd party asset instantly inactivating the prefab since my character collider was inside the prefabs trigger collider.